# How to write a function pointer to a function returning a function pointer to a function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I want to assign a function's address to a function pointer, but the function to be addressed returns a function pointer with the same signature as itself, causing it to recurse in a way that I can't write the return type at all, for the function pointer or even the function declaration itself...

I guess a way of simplifying the problem so it's not confusing:

How could I write a function declaration such, that it can return a pointer to itself (or any other function with the same signature)?

```
????? function(int a){
    // could be this function, or another with the same signature, 
    return arbitraryFunction;  
}

?????(*func)(int) = function;  // same problem as above
```

**edit:**

For now I have a solution, though I won't post it as an answer because it's aggressively ugly.  It gets rid of the recursion by simply returning a raw `void*` pointer as the return type, and ends up taking the following form:

```
void* function(int parameter){
    return arbitraryFunction; // of the same signature
}

void*(*func)(int) = function; 
func = reinterpret_cast<void*(*)(int)>(func(42));  // sin
```

**edit2:**

It seems casting between function pointers and regular pointers is UB, so I can't use `void*` in this case...

To answer one of the comments, this is for passing control between multiple "main" loops in my program, with each loop getting it's own function.  There's a lot of ways to do this, but returning function pointers (or NULL to terminate the program) mid-loop *seemed* like the simplest method, but I didn't anticipate that pointers to data and pointers to function addresses would be incompatable with each other.  I think returning polymorphic function objects will end up being the more sane option in this case.

Comment: I guess you cannot do that, at least not easily.

Comment: I wonder if returning `void*` as the function's and function pointer's return type, will let me avoid the recursive declaration...

Comment: BTW, even Ocaml disallow that, unless you invoke `ocamlc` with `-rectypes` (for *recursive types*)

Comment: May you tell us the exact problem? There could be better solutions for it.

Comment: Casting a void* to a function pointer is not legal by the standard, but see my solution below.

Comment: @black - I amended the question to include the bigger problem I was trying to solve

Comment: Are you interested in the return value of the pointed-to function or will you always be ignoring what it returns?

Comment: @VaughnCato - the pointed to function has it's return value assigned to... itself I suppose?  It looks like `func = func()` in a loop where `func != nullptr`  (though now I know that second statement might not be allowed)

Comment: If you are getting a function pointer, presumably it is to eventually be able to call the pointed-to function.  I'm wondering if, once you do call it, are you interested in the return value?

Comment: Did you really want a C++ answer? (all answers so far are C answers)

Comment: @Clairvoire This is impossible because type checker would have to check infinite types. That's a hard task even for simple type systems with equirecursive types. Obviously there's no such thing in C++. Though you can always wrap it into a `struct`. This is an equivalent of isorecursive types as now compiler may determine pack/unpack borders by the fact you've created/accessed your structure.

Comment: @Clairvoire Regarding `edit2`, you should take a look at Boost Coroutine and Boost Asio libraries.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `void*`, because no guarantee that a `void *` can hold a function pointer. You can use `void(*)()` as a workaround:

```
typedef void(*void_func)();
typedef void_func (*func_type) (int);
void_func arbitraryFunction(int a) {
    // could be this function, or another with the same signature, 
    cout << "arbitraryFunction\n";
    return nullptr;  
}
void_func function(int a) {
    // could be this function, or another with the same signature, 
    return (void_func) arbitraryFunction;  
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    func_type f = (func_type) function(0);
    f(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/hEmPyq)

C99 [6.2.5/27]:

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers to
>   qualiﬁed or unqualiﬁed versions of compatible types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to
>   structure types shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers
>   to other types need not have the same representation or alignment
>   requirements.

C99 [6.3.2.3/8]:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer.

Comment: it can't return void though, because `func` will need to match the function that returned it, which returns `func`

Comment: Note that converting a function pointer to a `void*` is UB and is neither required to be supported nor that its value is preserved while converting back and forth.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @Clairvoire I've fixed my answer.

Comment: The OP was tagged `C++`, yet you quote the C99 standard. How can that possibly answer the question correctly?

Answer (score 5):

The trick in C is to take advantage of the fact that any kind of function pointer can be cast to any other kind of function pointer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void(*emptyfunc)(void);
typedef emptyfunc (*funcptr2)(int);

funcptr2 strategy(int m)
{
  printf("Strategy %d.\n", m);
  return (funcptr2)&strategy;
}

int main (void)
{
  const funcptr2 strategy2 = (funcptr2)strategy(1);
  const funcptr2 strategy3 = (funcptr2)strategy2(2);
  strategy3(3);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Each pointer to a strategy is always in a type that can be called once, and the return value is put back into a form that can be called once again.

In C++, you would declare a function object:

```
class strategy {
  public:
  virtual const strategy& operator()(int) const = 0;
}
```

An instance of this class can be called like a function.

Comment: How to return a reference of other function object from a member function?

Comment: @songyuanyao I’m not sure I understand the question, but one approach would be to make strategy an abstract base class and have subclasses that implement different strategies.  Then you could return instances of those.

Comment: I mean in one of the subclasses, when you return another subclass, you have to keep the reference valid, by using global variable, etc.

Comment: You just need to declare the objects before you refer to them.  They might be singletons.  Alternatively, you could adjust the interface so that a meta-strategy is a higher-order function taking strategies as input.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you are trying to do is a more complex version of something like this:

```
typedef MainLoop *MainLoop(); // not legal

extern MainLoop* main_loop_1();
extern MainLoop* main_loop_2();

MainLoop* main_loop_1()
{
    // do some work here
    return main_loop_2;
}

MainLoop* main_loop_2()
{
    // do some work here
    return main_loop_1;
}

int main()
{
    MainLoop f = main_loop_1;

    for (;;) {
      f = f();
    }
}
```

A workaround is to wrap the function pointer in a struct:

```
struct MainLoop {
    MainLoop (*function_ptr)(); // legal
};

extern MainLoop main_loop_1();
extern MainLoop main_loop_2();

MainLoop main_loop_1()
{
    // do some work here
    return {main_loop_2};
}

MainLoop main_loop_2()
{
    // do some work here
    return {main_loop_1};
}  

int main()
{
    MainLoop f{main_loop_1};

    for (;;) {
       f = f.function_ptr();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem in the question is the function-pointer analogue of declaring a linked list, and this answer is how you do it in both cases.